# ENIG or conductive carbon for small-run remote control PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, remote-control

I'm working on a replacement PCB for a handheld consumer IR remote control transmitter that uses standard silicone keypads. The client plans to run only around 50 of them. I prototyped the new board using standard-thickness ENIG because it was easy, and it works fine. I used ENIG in a similar prototype about a year ago, and it's still working fine. However, I don't live in a particularly humid area.

Given the small expected quantity in this case, I am wondering whether for production we can use standard-thickness ENIG for the switch pads rather than printed conductive carbon. At these numbers, ENIG can be done more inexpensively, but I am concerned about its long-term reliability vs. conductive carbon in this application.

I've read a few things that address this question, both pro and con. However, they have all been speculative in nature. Does anyone have any solid experience they can point to?

Comment: How does the price compare if you do a hard gold finish? That's what they typically use for card-edge connectors, since ENIG's gold plating is too thin to survive much abuse.

Comment: I am about 80 percent confident that we did this when I worked for a toy company. We had buttons where a carbon puck contacted exposed ENIG pads to make the circuit. Depending on use we tested to something like 50 k cycles up to maybe 1 million cycles. I don't recall ever having to change anything due to cycle life test failures. But if you are using a switch where a metal dome contacts the ENIG pads, well that is beyond my experience.

Comment: @Hearth At these quantities,costs are roughly: regular thickness ENIG < conductive carbon < thicker ENIG < hard gold.

Comment: @Mithat Have you considered looking at other PCB manufacturers that may be able to do carbon mask cheaper than the one you're considering now?

Comment: @Hearth Two fab+assembly houses I typically use are able to do carbon mask, so I have considered those as well as another I trust. The results are the similar throughout. I'm reluctant to consider anyone else for this project without personal experience or a strong third-party endorsement.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with the switch supplier for their recommendations as your first stop, of course.

Recommendations (J.W. Electronic Components GmbH):

> a minimum layer of 30 -50 micro inches of gold over 100 - 200 micro
> inches of nickel is recommended for best switch performance.

That's **way** thicker than typical ENIG gold plating, but the nickel barrier thickness is comparable. So it might be suitable in your situation if you consider bare nickel acceptable.

Hard gold is problematic, because of expense, and because you have to provide connections to allow the electroplating, which are later removed. The dangling traces (aka antennas) can cause EMI issues.

There is a good overview of the mobile phone experience, which is gathered over huge production volumes, from smtnet [here](https://smtnet.com/library/files/upload/evolution-of-surface-finishes-%20mobile-phone.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I saw conductive carbon PCB pads used in conjunction with Silicon keypads where each key had a black conductive cap.

If the product you are replacing has carbon PCB pads, I would stick with carbon and wouldn't try ENIG.

ENIG has a thickness of 3 to 5 microns which is really small.